# How do I add up the values ​in the array with the values ​outside the array?

Tags: javascript

i want to make function for get the winner with two input integer, this function must have result first input is the winner if value biggest than second input

```
function winner(a, b) {
    let result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (a[i] > b[i]){
            result[0] += 1
        }
        if (a[i] < b[i]){
            result[1] += 1
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```

if input
a = 2
b = 3

output:
0,1

if input
a = 5
b = 3

output:
1,1

Comment: What is `a[i]` or `b[i]` supposed to do, when `a` and `b` are numbers? o.O

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1,0` for the second input? Just initialize with default values: `result = [0,0]`, remove the for loop and just use  `if(a < b)` instead of `a[i]`

Comment: Why is the "output" for `a = 5, b = 3` `1,1`? Why not `1,0`?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that a and b are arrays.

And that the example is a array of a = [2,5],b = [3,3] and so a wins once and b wins once.
If you get NaN as a result it is because you are adding 1 to a empty array ,result.

So the solution would be to change

```
let result = [];
```

to

```
let result = [0,0];
```

also you need to make the for loop for the length of the array so the 3 in the for loop needs to be changed to

```
for(let i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
```

Comment: `a = 2, b = 3` So, the inputs are not arrays

Comment: I think the example is not 2 examples but the explenation of one example the input is a = [2,5] b = [3,3] first the 2 and the 3 is compered and b wins so result  = [0,1] then 5 and 3 are compered and a wins so result = [1,1]

Answer (score 0):

Why not return the result of the checks?

```
return [+(a > b), +(a < b)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear
1.a & b are numbers , they are not arrays
2.you cant iterate over a numbers
3.kindly improve your question

And if you want to compare 2 numbers You can also use "Math.max()"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

If u want to only compare 2 numbers,you can also write by using ternary operator

return a > b ? [1,1] : [0,1]